# Problem in Pandas : impossible to do sum of int with arbitrary precision

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to do the sum of large integers in pandas and the answer is not as expected.

Input file : `my_file_lg_int`

```
my_int
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
```

Python code

```
file = 'my_file_lg_int'
data = pd.read_csv(file)
data['my_int'].sum()
```

The output is :

```
111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222
```

As integers are too long, they are not integers but strings.
So I tried `data = pd.read_csv(file,dtype = {'my_int': int})` but I have an overflow error. How could I solve it ?

Comment: Pandas is based on numpy, which is written in C and Fortran.  Those languages have 64-bit integers, but they do not have Python's arbitrary length integers.  You will have to do your processing in Python, not in pandas.

Comment: @Tim Roberts. I was afraid of that. Thanks for answer. Files come from C program but GNU MP is used. Is there a python alternative to pandas in such cases ?

Comment: One of my pet peeves here is that people automatically reach for `pandas` because it has cutesy importers for csv-like files, Excel files, and databases.  I know the code you have above is not your entire program, but THAT code can be done trivially using Python by itself with no modules.

Comment: I had two solutions that works. Thanks. It is difficult for me to choose which one is the best. Any criticism would be appreciated

Comment: Use whichever solution makes the most sense to you.  YOU are the one who has to support/extend it.

Comment: @medium-dimensional. I agree but not in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
df["my_int"].apply(int).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I made a comment in the question

Answer (score 2):

Many tasks are easier without hauling in the enormous pandas and numpy modules.

```
filename = 'my_file_lg_int'
mysum = sum( int(k.rstrip()) for k in open(filename) )
```

Comment: I agree. But my skill is low in pyhton. I konow what I have to do ...

Comment: My file has many columns. And with pandas it is easy. My example was only a sum up of my problem.

Comment: The `csv` module is easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module to solve this. According to the documentation:

> Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as large as needed for a given problem:

Since the number in any given row here has 102 digits, we can choose to set the precision to 103 digits. This method will not, however, work if a number in any row has more than 103 digits.

```
import pandas as pd 
import decimal
from decimal import Decimal

decimal.setcontext(decimal.Context(prec=103))

df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype={"my_int": Decimal})
x = Decimal("0")

for i in df['my_int']:
    x = x + Decimal(i)

print(x)
print(type(x))
```

This gives:

```
333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333 
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I made a comment in the question.