# Problem with apply(int) to convert string to int in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

This question follows the question: [Problem in Pandas : impossible to do sum of int with arbitrary precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74903173/7462275) and I used the accepted answer from there:  `df["my_int"].apply(int).sum()`

But it does not work in all cases.

For example, with this file

```
my_int
9220426963983292163
5657924282683240
```

The ouput is `-9220659185443576213`

After looking at the `apply(int)` output, I understand the problem. In this case, `apply(int)` returns `dtype:int64`.

```
0    9220426963983292163
1       5657924282683240
Name: my_int, dtype: int64
```

But with large numbers, it returns `dtype:object`:

```
0    1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111...
1    2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222...
Name: my_int, dtype: object
```

Is it possible to solve it with pandas ?
Or should I follow [Tim Robert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74903381/7462275) from the previous question?

## Edit 1:

Awful solution. A line is added to the end of the file with a large integer

```
my_int
9220426963983292163
5657924282683240
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

And after, sum is done on all lines except the last one :

```
data['my_int'].apply(int).iloc[:-1].sum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using Pandas:

```
sum(data[`my_int`].apply(int).to_list())
```

**Why do I say so?**

`df1`:

```
my_int
9220426963983292163
5657924282683240
```

`df2`:

```
my_int
9220426963983292163
5657924282683240
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Let **S1** and **S2** denote the sum of elements in the column `my_int` in `df1` and `df2`, respectively:

```
S1 = 9226084888265975403
S2 = 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111120337195999377086514
```

If we check the documentation of NumPy on [Overflow errors](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html#overflow-errors), we see that NumPy offers limited precision:

```
>>> np.iinfo(int)
iinfo(min=-9223372036854775808, max=9223372036854775807, dtype=int64)
```

The max number representable is smaller than both **S1** and **S2**.

The solution works without any trouble and gives the correct sum:

```
>>> df2['my_int'].sum()
9220426963983292163565792428268324011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>>> 
>>> df2['my_int'].astype(object).sum()
9220426963983292163565792428268324011111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>>>
>>> sum(df2['my_int'].apply(int).to_list())
11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111120337195999377086514
```

EDIT:
Prefer `sum` over `np.sum`:

```
>>> np.sum(df1['my_int'].apply(int).to_list())
>>> -9220659185443576213
>>> sum(df1['my_int'].apply(int).to_list())
>>> 9226084888265975403
```

---

Source of the calculation for sum of elements in the column `my_int` is WolframAlpha: [df1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=9220426963983292163+%2B+5657924282683240), [df2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=9220426963983292163+%2B+5657924282683240+%2B+11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111)

Comment: Not sure what is giving the negative answer for `df1`. I am not specifying any `dtype` while converting data to DataFrame. The column `my_int` has type `int64` once `df1` is generated.

Comment: I removed my comments because they were useless. Your solution was right.

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

```
df["my_int"].apply(int).astype(object).sum()
```

`apply(int)`: To avoid string concatenation with large numbers.

`astype(object)`: To convert `int64` to `object`.